# after authentication firebase is not re-directing the user to another page

Tags: javascript, firebase

the issue i'm having is that after the user is successfully authenticated in Firebase (no errors in the debug console of the browser) the JS file does not redirect the to the second page. I'm following the code provided by firebase and have searched in github too. At this point i'm not sure what i'm missing. in advance, thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <div>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Name"
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script>
      var config = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  <script src="webapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-div">
    <h2>Test2</h2>
    <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email..." />
    <input id="txtPass" type="password" placeholder="Password..." />
    <button type="button" onclick="login()" >Login Here</button>
  <div>
</body>
</html>




.JS file

function login() {
  email = document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
  password = document.getElementById('txtPass').value;
  loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');`enter code here`

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        alert('Wrong password, try again!.');
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
      console.log(error);
});
}
function initApp() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user) {
    // User is signed in
      window.location = 'secondpage.html';
 } else {
     alert('test!.');

}
}
)}
```

Comment: Can you try with `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href`

Comment: @Philip just tried both and same results. It authenticates but will not redirect to the secondpage.html.

Comment: Oh, Just had a quick look at the code, Doesn't seem like you're calling `initApp()` anywhere. You should use onAuthStateChanged outside of the function. So just remove initApp() { }